# App is not running in full screen in iOS8

Tags: screen, ios8

I have created application in xcode 5 for ios 7. now i migrated to ios 8.

Now the problem is application is not run in full screen.

http://s21.postimg.org/fjron66af/Screen_Shot_2014_09_26_at_12_56_25_pm.png

But its working fine in iOS7 .

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the launch image with updated resolution.

Comment: i have added launch image.But no use.